# How to prevent XCode5 from hanging/beachballing when opening a storyboard?

Tags: xcode5

Im working on a game I did create in Xcode 4.6 with storyboards.  A few weeks ago I opened it in Xcode5 and it worked fine.  I was asked to upgrade storyboard and it worked fine.  Its not a complex storyboard, only 4 scenes and all standard stuff.  Today I went in to try and open it again and xcode hangs and beach balls.  I have to force quit it and I do get a very large report which I have saved in a text file but would be too long to post here.

How do I even find out what is causing the problem more specifically in order to ask or google around for an answer?

Things Ive tried:
I have disabled source control
I cant select the storyboard in order to see the IB Document opens in version, because it hangs.

I think this is the relevant part of the crash report:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:670
>   Details:  Failed to run one shot request for IBLayoutConstraint,
>   IBUIButton, IBUILabel, IBUITextField, IBUIView, and
>   IBUIViewController.   Interface Builder encountered an error
>   communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash
>   report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash
>   reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their
>   content in your crash report.   Exception name: The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.) Exception reason:
>   (null) Exception backtrace:  (null) Exception info:{
>       IBUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed.
>   (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)\""; }   Function: void
>   IBAssertMarshallingFailure(NSString *_*strong, NSString **_strong)
>   Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1} Hints:
>   None

Comment: I don't understand why someone voted to close this.  It's not the same issue as the others in SO, I've checked.  And if you think it should be closed because it's a duplicate, post the duplicate's link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is what I did.

1. I opened up the Storyboard file from Finder, in TextEdit, saw the Autolayout property and decided to set it to `NO`.  I did this because I remember skimming through the Crash report, seeing something about constraints.
2. Then I opened the Storyboard from Finder, but this time in Xcode5.  It opened up the storyboard scenes but all scenes were pretty much blank.  Meaning I couldn't see any controls that were originally there. I thought this was due to removing autolayout. So I re-added the key `useAutolayout="YES"` into the xml in TextEdit. Then I opened up the Storyboard file again, in Xcode5 and it was still blank.
3. Then I decided that perhaps I needed to open the entire project in XCode5 to see if the controls were still there. I did but I still didn't SEE the controls, but in the Scene navigator I could expand the nodes and those controls appeared to be in there.
4. Finally I resolved each AL issue individually and now the storyboard items have reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to disable autolayout manually in the storyboard.  Right-click the storyboard -> Open As -> Source Code.  Find useAutolayout="YES" and change it to useAutolayout="NO".

This may only work with Mavericks OS and XCode 5.0.2.  XCode 5.0.2 has several "occasionally hangs" bug fixes.