# Created New Project and click on storyboard Xcode 5 crashes

Tags: ios, xcode5

Tried cleaning, restart and reboot did not work.

[image: Screenshot enclosed]

Comment: Please explain your problem with more details.

Comment: is it happening with other projects also?

Comment: SigABRT is the exception is occur in many scenarios , we cant define excat answer for this , put the break point and check once in step by step

Comment: is it must to use Xcode 5 ?, according to this source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152143/4557505 , issue is solved by opening same project in Xcode 6 for similar issue of storyboard, else try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19160861/4557505

Comment: I am a beginner, trying to learn in Xcode 5, i just created project and when I click storyboards it crashes when I run it gets interface error exit 255. I am not sure what details to add to let you understand the issue i am facing. I have checked the other links related to this problem (referred by pyro above) did not work any of it. the problem still persists; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XCode 5 has several "occasionally hangs" which bug fixed in letter version (Xcode 6 or Xcode 7)

So, it is better to upgrade your Xcode to Xcode 7.(may need to update mac OS X )

Or, uninstall and install your again your xcode

or, disable autolayout and try again

Comment: i am learning from tutorials written for Xcode 5; i tried to do those in Xcode 7 only to find myself with issues. So, i chose to do it in xcode5.

Comment: all thing of Xcode 5 has in Xcode 7 and in additions, the bug of Xcode 5 has removed in Xcode 7. So, I prefer to learn in Xcode 7. don't forget  that you can  read the book of [xcode 5] and write code in Xcode 7.

Comment: Thanks jamil for that input.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to xcode 6 ; problem solved; thanks everyone for your valuable inputs.